# Can malloc return same address in two different processes?

Tags: c, linux, malloc, virtual-memory

Suppose I have two process `a` and `b` on Linux. and in both process I use `malloc()` to allocate a memory,

Is there any chances that `malloc()` returns the same starting address in two processes?
If no, then who is going to take care of this.
If yes, then both process can access the same data at this address.

Comment: we are using virtual addresses!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> Is there any chances that malloc() return same starting address in two process.

Yes, but this is not a problem.

What you're not understanding is that operating systems firstly handle your physical space for you - programs etc only see virtual addresses. There is only one virtual address space, however, the operating system (let's stick with 32-bit for now) divides that up. On Windows, the top half (0xA0000000+) belongs to the kernel and the lower half to user mode processes. This is referred to as the 2GB/2GB split. On Linux, the divide is 3GB/1GB - see [this article](http://linux-mm.org/VirtualMemory):

> Kernel memory is defined to start at PAGE_OFFSET,which in x86 is 0XC0000000, or 3 gigabytes. (This is where the 3gig/1gig split is defined.) Every virtual address above PAGE_OFFSET is the kernel, any address below PAGE_OFFSET is a user address.

Now, when a process switch (as opposed to a context switch) occurs, all of the pages belonging to the current process are unmapped from virtual memory (not necessarily paging them) and all of the pages belonging to the to-be-run process are copied in (disclaimer: this might not exactly be true; one could mark pages dirty etc and copy on access instead, theoretically).

The reason for the split is that, for performance reasons, the upper half of the virtual memory space can remained mapped to the operating system kernel.

So, although malloc might return the same value in two given processes, that doesn't matter because:

1. physically, they're not the same address.
2. the processes don't share virtual memory anywhere.

For 64-bit systems, since we're currently only using 48 of those bits there is a gulf between the bottom of user mode and kernel mode which is not addressable (yet).

Comment: Actually it's a 3GB/1GB split, 0xc0000000 is the beginning address of the last gigabyte of a 32-bit address-space.

Comment: @Benoit in that case, I stuffed up my numbers. It's usually a 2GB/2GB split on Windows unless you explicitly ask for it to be [`/LARGEADDRESSAWARE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wz223b1z(v=vs.80).aspx)

Comment: I didn't know for Windows, ty for the info. I pointed out that because the Linux's kernel space begins at 0xc0000000 as you mentionned it.

Comment: @Benoit that's a point - the OP did tag his Q linux. I'll update, thanks :)

Comment: on the fourth line, the second "virtual" should be "physical", no?

Comment: @Jens I think I mean virtual (but bear with me, I could be wrong). As I understand it, "virtual memory" is a processor feature which is either on or off, and there's only one space for it; however, the kernel maintains a mapping per-process which specifies what physical memory is mapped where. So the user-mode side of the vm is cleared when you switch processes and the new process loaded in (mapped). However, it doesn't swap the kernel pages and that range is always mapped to every process regardless. That said - if I've made an error do feel free to correct me :)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, `malloc()` can return the same pointer value in separate processes, if the processes run in separate address spaces, which is achieved via virtual memory. But they won't access the same physical memory location in that case and the data at the address need not be the same, obviously.

Answer (score 1):

Process is a collection of threads plus an address-space. This address-space is referred as *virtual* because every byte of it is not necessarily backed by physical memory. Segments of a virtual address-space will be eventually backed by physical memory if the application in the process ends up by using effectively this memory.

So, `malloc()` may return an identical address for two process, but it is no problem since these *malloced* memories will be backed by different segments of physical memory.

Moreover `malloc()` implementation is moslty not reentrant, therefore calling `malloc()` in differents threads sharing the same address-space hopefully won't result in returning the same virtual address.

Comment: Two threads calling `malloc()` can't modify the bookeeping strucutures at the same time. Some mecanisms shall make `malloc()` kind of thread-safe, yes.

Comment: True, either inside malloc()/free() or outside.